# Magento 2 : How can i add Icons to the user links such as "My account" Login" Sign in etc

Tags: magento2, toplinks

Further in Magento 1, I  could just edit the html template file and do anything I could imagine. Now with this complicated with xml thing, extending templates etc. I'm confused.

What I' trying to do is the following :
`Text under` Icon on top.

I don't know where I can add that span tag before the text, so I can style them in CSS?

I looked into all files can't find it.

Below is an example of what I want to do.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass an arguments in `default.xml` for add class in account link:

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
 <arguments>
       <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
       <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="true">account-link</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: Dipseh, i put the code into default.xml and it removed the link "my account" instead of adding class.. the html code is not there.

Comment: Add this block under this : `<referenceBlock name="top.links"> <block> </referenceBlock>`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using **icomoon** or **fontawesome** and include the icons on a "before" element for each link with less/css targeting the class.

Does this help or you need an example?

Comment: don't i need to make a <span class="icon"> </span>  first before the link? I go try now.!

Comment: Hi Vlad, so i tried i got the "icon showing up" only when i add a class "to the ahref tag...so i have to be able to add a class tag to the url...so i can put the icon :before so both are "links"...

Comment: You can do something lie this `li.authorization-link a:before {css declarations}` so you don't need to add a class on the <a> element and you can style depending on <li>

Answer (score 1):

**You have to pass an arguments in default.xml for add class in account link:**

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
  <arguments>
   <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
   <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="true">account-link</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```

Use font awesome css

```
.account-link {
  display: inline-block;
 font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
 font-size: inherit;
 text-rendering: auto;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.account-link:before {
  content: "\f007";
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```